# Custom class variables in a Java Bean

Tags: java, javabeans

I was reading about Java beans, and all the examples I came across use standard Java types (String, int, etc) for class variables. Can I use variables of my own class type in a bean?

Eg.

```
class MyBean implements java.io.Serializable{
    MyObj mo;
    public MyBean(){}
    //Getter and setter for mo
}
```

(Writing this from a phone, so apologize for no formatting)

Comment: Yes you can. When reaching your PC, try it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You can implement your own business logic using POJO defined by yourself plugging reusable components as well.

If you use JSF remember to create setter and getter for your variables if you want to access them from your JSP/Facelets pages. The naming convention is pretty standard, if you have a String named 'foo' the framework will call the

```
public String getFoo() 
{ 
  return foo;
}
```

method.